# Problem with two loops on rendering in calendar

Tags: development

I have got problem with two loops. If I adding one its good, but with more it duplikates or more the values.
I put this 3 Values {1/8, 1/8, 3/8} And want to get in sum 5/8. Because 1/8+1/8+3/8 = 5/8

I geting 3/8, 3/8, and 9/8

I want one Sum not three or more. Now after puts to exercise  {1/8, 1/8, 3/8} i get:

[image]

Here is my code.

```
  else
        {
            query1.Query = String.Format(FullQuery, "Dzien", dateISO, DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);
            query1.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Kontrakt' /><FieldRef Name='Procenty' />";
            query1.ViewFieldsOnly = true;

            SPListItemCollection listaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt = witryna.Lists["Szczegoly"].GetItems(query1);



            // Gdy nie ma zaznaczonej osoby to wtedy wyświetlamy wszystkie daty urlopów 
            foreach (SPListItem olistaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt in listaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt)
            {

                e.Cell.Style.Add("background-color", "#F5BCA9");
                e.Cell.CssClass = "dni_swiateczne";
                e.Cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(("<p style='color:blue; font-size:8px;'>" + olistaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt["Kontrakt"].ToString() + "</p><p style='color:#5D198E;'>" + olistaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt["Procenty"].ToString().Substring(3) + "</p>")));

                var query3 = new SPQuery();
                query3.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Dzien' /><Value Type='DateTime'>" + e.Day.Date.ToShortDateString() + "</Value></Eq></Where>";
                SPListItemCollection itemColl = witryna.Lists["Szczegoly"].GetItems(query3);
                int sumaProcentow = 0;
                foreach (SPListItem item in itemColl)
                {
                    int index;

                    index = olistaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt["Procenty"].ToString().IndexOf("#");
                    string procentKolejny = Convert.ToString(olistaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt["Procenty"]).Substring(index + 1,1);

                    sumaProcentow += int.Parse(procentKolejny);
                }

                e.Cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(("Suma = " + sumaProcentow.ToString() + "/8")));
                if (sumaProcentow > 8)
                {
                    e.Cell.Style.Add("background-color", "#FF0000");
                    e.Cell.CssClass = "dni_swiateczne";
                }
            }

            }
```

**Please help.**

Comment: Grzegorz,

Can you please post the value for `olistaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt["Procenty"]`

Comment: There is lookap field : "6;#1/8" so i geting read only 1/8 - thats why this code because i want only "1", and next add them. 
 index = olistaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt["Procenty"].ToString().IndexOf("#");
                    `string procentKolejny = Convert.ToString(olistaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt["Procenty"]).Substring(index + 1,1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `olistaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt["Procenty"]` use `item["Procenty"]`

```
foreach (SPListItem item in itemColl)
{
   int index;

   index = item["Procenty"].ToString().IndexOf("#");
   string procentKolejny = Convert.ToString(item["Procenty"]).Substring(index + 1,1);

   sumaProcentow += int.Parse(procentKolejny);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your issue. Say your outer for each loop iterates 3 times. For each iteration, you are querying for your number values and adding each of them to the "sum". Do you really want to add them all **each time** the outer loop iterates?

Look at the values in the top left red box on the 23rd.

1/8 -> suma = 3/8

1/8 -> suma = 3/8

3/8 -> suma = 9/8

Each is multiplied three times over because your loop is iterating three times.

1/8 + 1/8 + 1/8 = 3/8

3/8 + 3/8 + 3/8 = 9/8

You should think through your logic a little bit here.

Comment: I know, I wont only add one time. Only one, but i don't knowed how it done.